# less redundant way to concatenate html with using ajax

Tags: javascript

Hi: I'm a beginner with using javascript and devloping webs. I frequently use ajax to load page content. One thing I found very annoying to do is to concatenate large paragraph of html by hand, such as the following:

```
html += '<div class="my-container record-content list-item">';
html += '<div class="my-container record-content list-row list-item-title">';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>purchase ID:&nbsp'+data['purchase_id']+'</p>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>'+purchase_date+'</p>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container record-content list-row">';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<h4>'+data['departure_city']+'</h4>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container icon-wrapper right-arrow">';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<h4>'+data['arrival_city']+'</h4>';
html += '</div>';                   
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container record-content list-row">';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>time</p>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>'+departure_time+'</p>';
html += '</div>';       
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>'+data['airline_name']+'</p>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>'+data['flight_num']+'</p>';
html += '</div></div>';
html += '<div class="my-container record-content list-row">';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>passenger</p>';
html += '</div>';
html += '<div class="my-container text-wrapper list-text-wrapper">';
html += '<p>'+data['passenger_list']+'</p>';
html += '</div>';                               
html += '</div>';                                   
html += '</div>';
return html;
```

Is there any nicer way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to accomplish? Is your html static? If it is so, then why don't you just simply use html? If it is not, why would you have so many concatenation?

Comment: Make abstract methods that utilize `document.createElement` or use `<template>` tags + replace

Answer (score 1):

Aside from some helper function, template literals allow you to write multi-line strings. Use backticks:

```
let html = `
    <div class="my-container record-content list-item">
    <div class="my-container record-content list-row list-item-title">
    // etcetera
`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Another follow up question is that does using advanced framework like react helps reduce such scenario? I found it not very elegant :)

Comment: It really depends. React can also be very inelegant in a more complicated way. But it looks like you are loading html that could be turned into a component. If you are returning lots of components via Ajax, maybe react would help you build and manage components.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Basically, you start your string with backticks/grave accent (`)

```
html = `
   <div>
      <p>${variable}</p>
   </div>
`;
```